# Best practice for inserting log data from a rails app to mongodb

Tags: ruby-on-rails, mongodb, logging, analytics

I'm trying to figure out the best way to get log data into mongodb. Let's I want to create a simple mongo collection that will track all traffic on my site. I have thought of some possible solutions but I'm not sure if its clean:

Option 1: Add a before filter in the application controller and use MongoMapper to create/update a record in mongo when a user hits my site. A possible downside would be if a page is cached and the rails stack is not hit. I also don't like the idea of muddying up the controller and throwing in more work when what I already need is being output to a log.

Option 2: Somehow tail the apache log and as new data comes in, throw it in mongodb. Are there any tools that can observe/tail a log?

Any refinements or better options out there?

Answer (score 0):

Don't reinvent the wheel, Github is your friend.

Short search coughed up this: https://github.com/ClarityServices/semantic_logger

or maybe this:

http://blog.treasure-data.com/post/13766262632/real-time-log-collection-with-fluentd-and-mongodb